# React MUI: How can I override a primary color in a theme palette for Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using an external template with MUI and I'd prefer to override the primary colour palette in a configuration file in my project, I'd basically like to clone the current theme with all its config (like typography, breakpoints, etc) and only override a few values, maybe primary and secondary colour, but I'd like a scalable solution where I can add more configurations in a future.

I know that you can use different ThemeProviders in your app, passing the theme config, so my approach was to create a customThemeProvider where I get the current theme and do a deepmerge with my custom options...basically I've got a palette like this

```
import { pink, yellow } from "@mui/material/colors";

const appTheme = {
  palette: {
    primary: yellow,
    secondary: pink,
  }
};

export default appTheme;
```

and my themeProvider would be like this

```
import {ThemeProvider, useTheme} from "@mui/material";
import {Theme} from "@mui/material/styles";
import {deepmerge} from "@mui/utils";
import {ThemeOptions} from "@mui/material/styles/createTheme";

const CustomThemeProvider = (props : {customThemeOptions: Partial<ThemeOptions>, children : React.ReactNode})=>{
  const appTheme = useTheme()
  const customTheme = deepmerge(appTheme,props.customThemeOptions)

  return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default CustomThemeProvider
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the new palette is never applied, I also tried passing a theme instead of a themeOptions, using CreateTheme({palette: {...}}), but that doesn't work either.

Do you know what could be the problem here or if there is another solution where I can achieve a similar result?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: The `CustomThemeProvider` seems to be using `useTheme` to access a theme object from an outer provider. Is there another `ThemeProvider` that wraps the `CustomThemeProvider`?

Comment: yes @JohnLi correct, there is another ThemeProvider (the template default)  and this would be used as a child of these and wrapping my components...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have a base theme and a nested custom theme, which extends the base config and only overrides a few values, the MUI [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme) seems to suggest providing a callback function for the custom theme provider to access and extend the base.

Tested the example in a demo here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zjsv94?file=demo.js)

```
const baseTheme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: 300,
    },
  },
  palette: {
    primary: pink,
    secondary: deepOrange,
  },
});

//  Custom theme to extend the base theme
const customTheme = (theme: ThemeOptions) =>
  createTheme({
    ...theme,
    palette: {
      ...theme.palette,
      primary: teal,
    },
  });

//  Wrapped by an outer theme provider
const MyCustomProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
};
```